# Created and Updated by User fields, correct way to handle in MVC pattern

Tags: php, codeigniter, propel

I would like the valuable opinion of this community about a design decision.

I'm using CodeIgniter paired with propel.
I recently had to add an updated_by field in all existing tables and I obviously had to refactor all usages.

The user object is stored inside a library and (assuming all login credentials match) can be accessed with:

```
$this->auth->getUser(); //Returns a propel collection
```

I would ideally like to create something automatic (kinda like the timestampable behaviour).
There is an easy way to achieve this using something like this (don't mind the code too much, just jotted it down here out of memory, just get the idea):

```
public function preSave(\PropelPDO $con = null)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $user = $CI->auth->getUser();
    $this->setUserRelatedByUpdatedBy($user)
    if(is_null( $this->getUserRelatedByCreatedBy() ) )
    {
       $this->setUserRelatedByCreatedBy($user);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

The issue is that in this case the model is directly interacting with a codeigniter library, is this a violation of the MVC paradigm?

The other way to achieve this would be to add setUserRelatedByUpdatedBy and setUserRelatedByUpdatedBy on every controller when I'm saving data, that would be more strictly MVC, but I would be repeating myself with the same exact same lines everywhere.

How would you handle this case? Is there a proper way to automagically achieve something like a timestampable behaviour for user creating/updating rows?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @tereško what does this have to do with anything? A framework is just a framework, is how you use it that matters.

Comment: @0plus1: don't take tereško's comment personally. His style is frequently abrasive, and he tends to prefer technical absolutism over civility. I've commented to him directly several times to soften his commenting stance, to no avail. Reported to mod anyway, and +1 for remaining polite!

Answer (score 2):

Thumb rule which I've adapted lately is this:

## Library

Libraries must be as independent as possible. In many cases you might not even use `get_instance()` because the library is supposed to handle most things within itself.
Think of a library as a generic solution for a problem, like CodeIgniter's own libraries most/all of them are independent and gives a specific purpose.

You read `Form_validation` and that's exactly what it does. You don't need other libraries or models for it to work. A good library is one that everyone can use for their own app by simple changing the `$config` values.

Libraries should be able to use database queries in cases such as the `session` library; by using a table name that's set inside a config file.

## Model

Models *should* be related to database queries as much as possible, but more importantly, a model is made for your project. That's what differs libraries and models apart. The typical problem I used to stumble upon was this; if my model is *only* supposed to handle database calls, where do I put my non-database functions that are specific for my project? They shouldn't be in libraries, and it doesn't make sense to have them in helpers, so where do I put them?

My solution for this is using a *general* model. While all my other model files ends with `_model`, I have one model called `general` which I use to load other models with inside `application/models/general`. If I run `$this->general->load('utester')`, I can access the new model through `$this->general->utester`.

Now, this can be questioned etc. but this is my conclusion after I've worked for 3 years with CodeIgniter; a framework that basically lets you do anything you want. Inside `$this->general`, I *know* the logic isn't directly related to database queries. It's function could be assembling the array for a `form_dropdown()`, it could be a model for my login behavior or what not.

## Helper

Helpers are most ideal for parsing inside view files. Even though you can use `$this` inside views, it's most encouraged to process as much as possible on server side before sending the variables to the view, and what's left should be parsed with helper functions. If a function is used much both in views and controllers, you may as well have it as a helper.

Helpers should *never* need to use database queries.

I've made my own solution for this conflict, and I hope to have inspired you at least a little to come up with your own solution. Don't try to find the "best" solution in CodeIgniter, go with the one that makes the most sense without getting bad feelings about it. CodeIgniter in my eyes means freedom to find your own personal solutions.

And I don't mind hearing your opinions of my approach. It might considered incorrect by some, but let the critic be your opinion and nothing more.

1) Code for my custom **application/models/general.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* Used for Model scalability */
class General extends CI_Model {

    var $loaded     =   array();

    function load($mix)
    {
        $arr_load           =   array();
        $boo_is_array       =   is_array($mix);
        $boo_return_class   =   ! $boo_is_array;
        if ($boo_is_array)
            $arr_load   =   $mix;
        else
            $arr_load[] =   $mix;

        foreach ($arr_load as $int_key => $str_class) {

            $str_lower  =   strtolower($str_class);
            $str_name   =   ucfirst($str_class);

            $str_file   =   APPPATH . "models/general/{$str_lower}.php";

            $boo_success    =   FALSE;
            if (file_exists($str_file))
                if ( ! in_array($str_lower, $this->loaded)) {

                    require_once $str_file;

                    $this->$str_lower   =   new $str_name();
                    $boo_success        =   TRUE;

                }

            if ( ! $boo_success)
                unset($arr_load[$int_key]);

        }

        if ($boo_return_class)
            return $this->$str_lower;

        return (bool) count($arr_load);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is very interesting, how in your way of doing things would you put the authorization library?

Comment: In my latest project, I made a library that handles `login()`, `logout()` and `validate()` (check if username and password is supplied). All values; post names, session names and callback function for checking password are config values which can be changed through normal config behavior. The callback function is in **MY_Controller.php**. So basically the library is independent, and all set values are using in the views, callback function and so on.